# Error with virtualenv when I type deactivate IOError: [Errno socket error] [Errno -2] Name or service not known

Tags: python, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

When I type deactivate to come out of virtualenv, I get error as:

`IOError: [Errno socket error] [Errno -2] Name or service not known.`

Also libraries which I had installed out of virtualenv (i.e. default Python path) are not getting imported in vitualenv. E.g I installed NLTK in default Python path, but I am getting error while importing it in virtualenv. But all of this was working properly one day before.

Comment: Delete the virtualenv and recreate it again. See if the error is reproducible